# 2 times event firing due to script block

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.InternalSearchKeyword').keyup(function () {
            clearTimeout(typingTimer);
            if ($('.InternalSearchKeyword').val) {
                typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTypingKeyword, doneTypingInterval);
            }
        });

        function doneTypingKeyword() {
            alert('Hello');
            debugger;
        }
    });
</script
```

my problem is its firing 2time when i try to run the program and when i tried to debug it in IE i noticed that the script block is loading again the javascript is there a posible way to stop script block from firing the script? i'm developing in MVC 4.

what happend is when the document is ready the javascript will load.
and after loading it the scripblock will load it again thats why it fires two event 
and when im having an event as well it keeps on firing two times.

Comment: `if($('.InternalSearchKeyword').val)` should be `if($('.InternalSearchKeyword').val())` - `val` is a function, so will always resolve to `true`, you need to call it to get the actual value.

Comment: "when the document is ready the javascript will load. and after loading it the scripblock will load it again "  What makes you think this block is loaded twice? Aren't you including it twice instead? BTW, once fired, pseudo ready event unbound attached handlers, so no way same handler can be called twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with ASP.NET, but if the code is executing twice for whatever reason you can modify the jQuery to account for that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function handleSearchKeyword() {
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        if ($('.InternalSearchKeyword').val()) {
            typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTypingKeyword, doneTypingInterval);
        }
    }

    $('.InternalSearchKeyword').off('keyup', handleSearchKeyword).keyup(handleSearchKeyword);

    function doneTypingKeyword() {
        alert('Hello');
        debugger;
    }
});
```

That will remove the `keyup` handler running that function if it exists, and then bind a new `keyup` handler to execute that function. So, regardless of how many times the code is executed, there will only be a single event handler.